# How to work around transparent system colors when drawing with Core Animation layers on Mojave?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, nsview, macos-mojave

With dark mode in macOS 10.14 Mojave, most system colors are semi-transparent. That is to match control colors with the window background, which in turn is slightly tinted to match the desktop picture.

Now when building a view with overlapping CoreAnimation layers, things get messed up. Example:

[image: custom slider control]

This is a custom slider built with CALayers. The vertical track is a layer beneath the knob layer. Here's how I set the colors:

```
- (void)updateColors // Called from updateLayer()
{
    self.tickmarkLayer.strokeColor = [NSColor tertiaryLabelColor].CGColor;
    self.tickmarkLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;

    self.trackLayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor controlBackgroundColor].CGColor;
    self.trackLayer.borderColor = [NSColor tertiaryLabelColor].CGColor;
    self.trackLayer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    self.sliderLayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor controlColor].CGColor;
}
```

**Of course, I don't want the knob to be transparent, i. e. the track layer should not shine through. How can I work around this while preserving the dynamic tint?**

Ideally, one could access the the "effective" system colors with the current tint and no transparency. But I didn't find any API to do so.

A similar problem occurs when applying a shadow to layers that have transparent (system) colors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Does NSColor's `colorWithAlphaComponent:` do the trick for you?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1526906-colorwithalphacomponent?language=objc

i.e.

```
self.sliderLayer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor controlColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0f].CGColor;
```

It looks like darkMode sets the alpha component of control color to: `0.247059`

Comment: Well that way I can remove the alpha component, but along with that the tint of the window background will also go.

Answer (score 4):

Things I’d try:

- use two layers for the slider: one with window background color (to give it opaque background), then a layer with the same shape and controlColor on top.

See “Update Custom Views Using Established Methods“ in [Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface) to make sure the colors are dynamically updated.

- use NSBox instead of layers to draw the slider. Again, you might need two of them. But NSBox can automatically handle dynamic UI colors and tinting. See [windowBackgroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1528630-windowbackgroundcolor).

Comment: A first test with NSBox seems to solve the issue! Will update my question later with a comprehensive solution. Thanks!